# skaffold use one container as buildArg of another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tools

I want to build a container using the command say

skaffold build -f skaffold.yaml.A

The container built here I want to use in the next step as buildArgs

skaffold build -f skaffold.yaml.B

Is there a way to merge these two yamls? I mean use the first container as the buildArg for the next.

Can I use variables in buildArgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skaffold doesn't know how to do that for the moment